# Backbone.js - passing 2 models to 1 view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to pass 2 models to the view, but it seems it is not working. Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/kahhor/jp4B6/14/ As you can see second alert is showing undefined...

May be I have wrong approach. What I'm trying to do is: in `View1` bind event `'change'` to `Model1`... Than by clicking button in `View2`, call function in `Model1` which changes value, and automatically render `View1`, since it was binded to change event.

But don't forget that `View2` has also its own `Model2`, which I created outside the view and than passed it like `new View2({model:Model2});`.

It might looked confusing at first, but I think it is simple thing that backbone can do. I just don't know how to do it :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can access custom parameters (options) from

```
window.PopupView = new PopupView({ model: LeftNotificationM, model2: PopupM});
```

like this:

```
window.PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // code left out

    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind('change:notification_num', this.render);
        alert(this.model);
        // your model2 option:
        alert(this.options.model2);
    },

   // code left out
});
```

Conclusion: "unrecognized options" of a view can be found in `this.options`

Comment: Wow, than you it worked. I was stuck with 2 days :) I have just 2 questions. 1. Where can I read more about this.options, I saw it before, but I don't really understand how can I use it... 2. I guess you understand what I'm trying to do. I would like to know if it is good way of doing it? Or there some better (more correct way) of doing it?

Comment: Hi, 1) I just had a look at the source code [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-119) that's what I love about backbone.js: It's simple :) 2) A model may be attached to multiple views, that's ok. Just spend some attention on the naming "model2" isn't a very good name ;)

Comment: Yes I know, I just showing simple example :) Thank you again :)

Comment: It doesn't seem that the model2 event binding is working e.g., `model2.on('change:field', this.doSomething, this)`

Comment: How does this work when trying to template using both models?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683743/template-two-models-in-one-view-backbone-marionette

Answer (score 6):

I just found this question and Sled's answer via Google and it helped me a lot - but just to update this 2 year old question and perhaps save some other Googlers the headache:

> Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the
>   constructor as this.options, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

[Vitaliy's Answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19325531/490042) shows you how:

```
initialize : function (options) {
  this.options = options || {};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this patch and pass any options directly to view.

```
    Backbone.View.prototype._configureWithoutThis = Backbone.View.prototype._configure;
    Backbone.View.prototype._configure = function(options) {
      this._configureWithoutThis(options);
      _.extend(this, this.options);
    }
```